# IOS 7 UIAlertView add buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have `UIAlertView`:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                message:message
                                               delegate:[self class]
                                      cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

And i have array of titles that i want to add with :

```
for(NSString *buttonTitle in otherButtons)
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
```

And when the alert is shown in the screen the title is invisible.

Any idea why it happen?

Comment: Which title is 'invisible' ? - also where is `[alert show];` ?

Comment: Could you add printscreen?

Comment: Is title a valid NSString ? Couldn't it be nil ?